# Ordering in django/dnf by user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model post with field User (FK), can I order all the posts so that the current user's posts come first? For example in serializer class.
Or maybe I should write my own filter?

Comment: Can you add your model and current view/serializer?

Comment: you can create custom queryset in get_queryset() in your PostViewSet.